# How to migrate private files to azure so un-authenticated person can't have access?

Tags: database, azure, security, server, azure-storage

I am migrating whole site to azure, I have some private files on my server, which I want to transfer to azure. how to restrict public access to those files on azure? Those files are basically reports that only authenticated person can download. I don't want the un-authenticated person to even access to the link of that folder. How can i do that in azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest utilizing the Role-based Access Control (RBAC) feature available in Azure portal under resource groups. This option allows you to manage and/or restrict access to resources within your storage account. to View who has access to a specific resource, try the following:

```
1 -Select Resource groups in the navigation bar on the left.
2- Resource groups - icon
3- Select the name of the resource group from the Resource groups blade.
4- Select Access control (IAM) from the left menu.
5- The Access control blade lists all users, groups, and applications that have been granted access to the resource group.
```

To **remove access**:

```
1- Hover your cursor over the name of the assignment that you want to remove. A check box appears next to the name.
   2-Use the check boxes to select one or more role assignments.
   3- Select Remove.
   4- Select Yes to confirm the removal.
```

**Full article can be found here:**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

If you are concerned about public read access as you mentioned "By default, a container and any blobs within it may be accessed only by the owner of the storage account.", you can change and check on these options under Container permissions by doing the following:

```
> To set container permissions in the Azure portal, follow these steps:
> Open your Storage account blade in the portal. You can find your
> storage account by selecting Storage accounts in the main portal menu
> blade. Under BLOB SERVICE on the menu blade, select Containers.
> Right-click on the container row or select the ellipsis to open the
> container's Context menu. Select Access policy in the context menu.
> Select an Access type from the drop down menu.
```

Full Article can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources